# How to access Google Photos Library API without CLIENT_SECRET in android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, credentials, google-photos-api

I'm building an android application(no backend server) using **Photos Library API** , it access to google photos and manage image .

There are three step:

1. Google Sign in
2. Authentication app use Google Photos
3. Access Google Photos

Im stucking with step 3

First , I create an client :

```
            settings = PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder()
                    .setCredentialsProvider(
                            FixedCredentialsProvider.create(getUserCredentials(token)))
                    .build()
            return PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings)
```

in getUserCredential method, it return a Credential:

```
    fun getUserCredentials(token: String): Credentials? {
        val a = AccessToken(token, null)

        return UserCredentials.newBuilder()
                .setClientId("client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .setClientSecret("")
                .setAccessToken(a)
                .build()
    }
```

But problem is I can't find Client Secret in Google Console, it just have Client ID. I'm tried with Json file downloaded from Console, but it doesn't have client_secret field, and it return null on this field

Question is : How to get **Client Secret** for Android Application, or another way to get Credential without client secret

Can I have a solution for this problem ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same issue. You don't have to use exactly client secret from Android Application. You could use client secret from Web App, and your android app still work fine

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion and its work even though I don't understand why. Could you explain more ???

Answer (score 0):

From the resulting OAuth client dialog, download the JSON file containing your client configuration. You client details consist of the following:

- Client ID
- Client secret

Comment: after download Json file, it have name is "client_secret_.....apps.googleusercontent.com", and details have fields : "client_id" ; "project_id" ; "auth_uri"; "token_uri" ; "auth_provider_x509_cert_url" . But doesn't have **"client_secret"** field

Comment: You need to configure OAUth 2.0 credentials (client ID and secret) and not an API key. More details are in the developer documentation here: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started#request-id

Comment: I made the Oauth 2.0 Credential before, not API key. And with application type = android when create Credential, it doest have client secret